# Grouping and adding large dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a big dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
  from_node  to_node  0
0                     
1 1907 2343 0.1
2 2343 2344 0.2
3 2050 2051 0.1
4 2050 2344 0.4
 ....
```

I want to create 2 new dataframes
on with node_loss so the data from the 0 column grouped and added with an index from the from_node and one dataframe withe the node_add so the same data from the 0 column grouped and added with an index from the to_node column.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. Here, *show* (not just describe) us your desired output and what you've tried already.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i'm new here. Will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys are [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group with nodes, [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to aggregate (sum) by the grouped nodes, and [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename your columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"from_node": [1907, 2343, 2050, 2050], "to_node": [2343, 2344, 2051, 2344], "0": [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]})
new_df1 = df.groupby("from_node").agg({"0": "sum"}).rename(columns={"0": "node_loss"})
new_df2 = df.groupby("to_node").agg({"0": "sum"}).rename(columns={"0": "node_add"})
```

Now `new_df1` and `new_df2` are what you want.

BTW, since you are tagging Python 2.7, please also note that [pandas is dropping Python 2.7](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#plan-for-dropping-python-2-7).

Answer (score 0):

its quite easy:
assuming the name of dataframe is df
make a new dataframe: 
`new1=pd.DataFrame`
add the columns you want together:

`new1["from_node"]=df["from_node"]`

`new1["node_loss"]=df[0]`

similarly you can repeat the same for the second dataframe as well:

make a second new dataframes: `new2=pd.DataFrame()`

add the columns you want together:

`new2["to_node"]=df["to_node"]`

`new2["node_loss"]=df[0]`

You get two new dataframes with the corresponding values